Why is 的 not Teku or Chaki?
In Japanese there are many Go-on/Kan-on pairs that one end with I and one ending with U, if u is the default filler vowel, then why don't all of them end with U?

Perhaps you can provide some go-on/kan-on example pairs that you have observed

I believe the answer might be essentially a manifestation of vowel harmony.
Japanese doesn't do this much, as compared to other languages like Turkish or Hungarian.  However, in the case of on'yomi pronunciations borrowed from Middle Chinese words, at least for those ending in /-k/, I think the distribution of excrescent (additional) "neutral" vowels follows the frontness or backness of the nucleus vowel.
The excrescent neutral vowels in Japanese are /u/ and /i/, both prone to devoicing in specific environments.  In Japanese phonology, /u/ is a back vowel, and /i/ is a front vowel.  So if the nucleus vowel of a Middle Chinese word was back, the excrescent vowel in Japanese that appears after the coda consonant in Middle Chinese will also be a back vowel.  Likewise, if the nucleus vowel of a Middle Chinese word was front, the excrescent vowel in Japanese that appears after the coda consonant in Middle Chinese will also be a front vowel.  The Japanese /a/ is technically a central vowel, but for these purposes, it appears to be treated as a back vowel.
So in looking at the on'yomi distribution of excrescent final  /-u/ as compared to /-i/, we see the following pattern:

/-u/ appears after a central or back nucleus vowel (again, in Japanese phonology, the central vowel is /a/, and the back vowels are /o/ and /u/)

Examples include chaku (not *chaki), oku (not *oki), fuku (not *fuki)


/-i/ appears after a front nucleus vowel (Japanese front vowels are /i/ and /e/)

Examples include shiki (not *shiku), teki (not *teku)




A bit about vowel harmony.
In Hungarian and Turkish, two languages that have definite and recognized vowel harmony and that I've also studied a bit, the vowel harmony follows this same pattern: front vowels tend to force other elements to have front vowels, and back vowels tend to force other elements to have back vowels.
I don't think this is any kind of obscure linguistic magic: I think it's simply a matter of the biomechanics of speech, and of the natural tendency towards laziness (or economy of motion) when speaking.  Saying a clear vowel that is either front or back, followed by a clear vowel of the opposite type, is more expensive, in terms of the effort and coordination required, than saying two vowels of the same type.  You simply have to move more of your mouth around to do that.
This is basically the same reason that English "going to" tends to collapse to "gunna" in everyday informal speech: it's simply less effort to say it that way.

I feel that "at least for those ending in /-k/" rather should be "only for those ending in /-k/", since for Middle Chinese /p/ coda, excrescent vowel in Sino-Japanese reading is always /u/ (e.g. MC /-ip/ > SJ /-ipu/ > /-iu/ > /-juː/), and for Middle Chinese /t/ coda, there was no excrescent vowel originally, and still so until at least 16th century (as attested in Portuguese sources).

@Arfrever, what of words like 一【いち】 or 日【にち】, or kanji with on'yomi ending in ち, like 越 with kan'on of おち（をち） and goon of えち（ゑち）? Are these later retconned reconstructions, like the invention of "yi" during the Meiji period?

Digging around in the 日葡辞書, I see cases with no excrescence, like "Xetbun" for modern せつぶん on this page (right-hand column), but then I also see that 八月 was apparently pronounced as "Fachiguachi" as shown here, with both 八 and 月 exhibiting excrescent final "-i". Interesting, and confusing.

For /t/ coda, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/106655 was asked, so I will respond there.

Table in Frellesvig (2010, page 283) suggests slightly different adaptation of MC *-k coda: (1) go-on: ku / {e, a, o, u} _, ki / {i} _; (2) kan-on: ku / {i, a, o, u} _, ki / {e} _.

@Arfrever, interesting. Presumably that reflects differences in the underlying Chinese source lects? I cannot think of nor find examples of on'yomi ending in /-eku/ (albeit I currently have limited access to my references). Does Frellesvig include any such instances?

I cannot find /-eku/ examples amongst official readings of jōyō kanji. Examples with /-iku/ would be: 育, 肉, 竹, 逐.

For /-iku/, I'm finding いく・きく・じく・ちく・にく・りく, but not the other initials, which is an oddly specific distribution: setting aside い and き, these are all coronal / alveolar initial consonants (and for that matter, the /k/ in き is more coronal in Japanese than is common in English). I wonder if the place of articulation impacted the choice of following neutral vowel?

Grepping in kanjidic dictionary allowed me to find 8 kanji, all of them with セク reading: 齪, 戹, 搤, 敫, 斁, 晹, 瀹, 齱. (So エク, ケク, ゲク, ゼク, テク, デク etc. are not attested in this dictionary.)

kanjidic also has 4 kanji with /-aki/, /-oki/ or /-uki/ readings: 擽 (フキ), 懝 (ゴキ), 赥 (コキ), 廙 (ヨキ).

Huh. Also apparently exceedingly rare. I can't find instances of these in use, making me wonder if these might be "theoretical" readings applied later, much like the Meiji-era "yi" and "wu".
