Did Middle Japanese really have final -t?
Like final -m and final -n which did exist to common knowledge, did final -t exist?
Portuguese sources speak of Japanese possessing a final -t in the past, but I am unsure if it about it's existence.
Does anyone know if this really was a common feature of Japanese in the past?

Can you provide some more details as to where you saw the mentioning of final -t or what led you to think that it might have existed?

In my knowledge of reconstructed Japanese phonotactics, final -m and -n were only possible through loanwords (most notably from Chinese) and vowel dropping (e.g. from ぬ and む), and they were allowed despite the simple phonological structure of Japanese because these are nasal consonants and do not obstruct airflow. -t violates the latter and I cannot recall any case of a loanword with a final -t that does not give rise to a completely separate syllable (e.g. realisation as ツ). It seems highly unlikely that the Japanese language used to allow words that end with a -t.

@KisaragiAyami, see the 1603 日葡辞書【にっぽじしょ】 / Vocabvlario Da Lingoa De Iapam. If we search for "xet" for instance, as the then-current Portuguese spelling of modern せつ, we find many examples. Other words with つ in a non-final location have that rendered as tçu.

The presence of the "tçu" spelling tells us that the Portuguese writers could clearly recognize when つ was pronounced with a vowel, suggesting that word-final "-t" was intentional.  It is unclear to me if this word-final "-t" was pronounced with an audible release (similar perhaps to how "hot" might be pronounced in English by careful speakers) or with no audible release (like "hot" where the speaker just ends with a stop, also a bit like the modern Korean pronunciation of final "-t" consonants).

@EiríkrÚtlendi, thank you for the reference. May I ask if devoicing was observed in Middle Japanese, or do we even have any such information? I suspect that the discrepancy between "t" and "tçu" may be due to devoicing of the vowel, similar to what you have suggested.

@KisaragiAyami, if the modern rendering of つ were pronounced without its vowel, that would collapse to something like /ts/, and I don't think Portuguese speakers of the time would confuse that with /t/. I did also find instances of modern せつ appearing word-medially and rendered as "xet-" in the Nippo Jisho, such as "Xetbun" on page 312 (right-hand column, further up from the highlighted word). Given Portuguese spelling then, this would have been pronounced a bit like /ʃetbun/, with no medial "s".

Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", pages 316-319):

11.4 Sino-Japanese syllable final /-t/
A famous feature of the Christian sources is the use of syllable final -t in the writing of SJ words both in word final and nonfinal syllables, e.g. (17). There is little doubt that this reflects contemporary pronunciation, as also shown for example by renjō (11.4.2).
(17)
fotnet suru 'get fever' (発熱)
connit 'today' (今日)
In NJ the words which in late LMJ had final /-t/ have an epenthetic vowel, usually /u/ (netsu 'fever'), but sometimes /i/ (konnichi 'today'). In earlier sources in Japanese script, these words are written with kana for tu (つ) or ti (ち), but it has recently been shown that a distinction also was made in some LMJ kana sources between -tu and -t, by using variant kana (hentaigana, see EMJ 6.1.2) which were originally used as equivalents for /tu/.
11.4.1 Sources of final /-t/
Final /-t/ is found among SJ words reflecting EMC *-t. Whereas EMC *-p and *-k were reflected in SJ vocabulary by /-pV/ and /-kV/, especially in SJ readings as -pu (> -u), -ku, and -ki (see 9.2.2.3), EMC *-t was in a number of SJ words reflected as final /-t/, with no epenthetic vowel. The orthographic categories of the kana do not provide for representation of /-t/ and seem to have used kana for tu or ti for /-t/. The use of hentaigana to represent /-t/ is a fairly new discovery and it has yet to be seen how widespread this practice was. In NJ SJ kanji readings EMC *-t is conventionally rendered as -ti in go-on and -tu in kan-on, and it is usually thought that SJ loanwords taken in from (Japano-Chinese or Sino-Japanese) go-on had final /-ti/, whereas words originating in kan-on had /-t/, written by kana for tu and later acquiring an epenthetic /u/ to give /tu/. This is almost certainly an overly simplistic view. For example, the SJ loanword for 'fever' 熱 was late LMJ net as shown by the Christian sources. In EMJ this was written as neti (cf. 9.2.3.2) whereas the NJ shape is netu. This indicates that the EMJ writing as neti was meant to represent /net/, and significantly, the initial /n-/ of these forms clearly show that they derive from go-on, corresponding to EMC *ɲiat, cf. 9.2.2. (For 熱 modern kanji dictionaries give go-on as netsu/nechi and kan-on as zetu.) All this strongly suggests that this go-on based SJ loanword was net until the beginning of NJ. Another similar example is late LMJ jitni /zit-ni/ 'really' which was written ziti-ni in EMJ (cf. 9.2.3.2), but which is cNJ jitu-ni. Again, this suggests that the form was zit from EMJ until early NJ, and also this is clearly go-on based, corresponding to EMC *ʑit. (For 実, modern kanji dictionaries give kan'yō-on as jitsu, go-on as jichi and kan-on as shitsu, showing, compared to the readings for 熱, some arbitrariness in the assignment of current forms to kan'yō-on or to one of the other layers of readings.)
Final /-t/ is almost entirely limited to SJ vocabulary, but it is also found in a very small number of variant shapes of native words in the Christian sources, whose regular shapes, however, have final vowels: ximot 'cane, rod (used in criminal punishment)' (~ /simoto/), carafit 'big box; lit. Chinese chest' (~ /karafitu/); tetdai 'help' (~ /tetudai/). Spelling variants by hentaigana in sources in Japanese script confirm that these words had final /-t/.
11.4.2 Renjō
Final /-t/ is also reflected in renjō, the process in which a final consonant is copied as the onset of a following syllable with initial vowel or glide (onset creation; see 7.2.1). Renjō after final /-t/ is in Arte (p. 637) said to be regular before va /wa/ which becomes ta after /-t/, so that for example taixetta /taiset-ta/ is from taixetua /taiset-wa/ 'importance-TOP'. The only examples given in Arte involve the topic particle wa, but in both shōmono and the early NJ kyōgen texts (13.3) there are also frequent examples of renjō after /-t/ before the accusative particle o, which becomes to. Through the period several lexical items are also
found, for example /settyoosyuu/ (Setchōshū) which is an alternative name for the mid fifteenth-century dictionary today known as Setsuyōshū /setuyoosyuu/, showing that it must earlier have been /set.yousyuu/, giving /setuyoosyuu/ by vowel epenthesis and /settyoosyuu/ by renjō). However, they are not many; the only two lexical forms included in Vocabulario with renjō after final /-t/ are xecchin /settin/ 'toilet; "tight spot"' (雪隠) <= set.in (mentioned also in 7.2.1 and still used in NJ) and xǒjenbattacu /syɔɔzenbattaku/ 'reward good, punish evil' <= syaũzen-bat.aku (賞善罰悪) which is no longer used.
By contrast, renjō after /N/ appears to have been far more widespread and regular. Thus, Arte (pp. 636-7) sets it out as a general rule of pronunciation, saying that for example sanya /san.ya/ 'mountains and fields' should be pronounced sannha /san.nya/; other examples are xinnhô /sin.nyoo/ 'trust' <= xinyô /sin.yoo/, ninguenna /ningen-na/ 'person-TOP' <= ninguenua /ningen-wa/. Also Vocabulario includes a number of forms with renjō, e.g. annon 'peace and quiet' (安穏, an + on) or innen 'destiny' (因縁, in + en), but sometimes notes that this is the actual pronunciation, although they are written differently, or 'correctly' should be pronounced without renjō. Both Arte and Vocabulario demonstrate awareness of renjō as a general, productive rule after /N/ and of the relationship between underlying and surface form. In addition, Vocabulario, while noting actual pronunciation, recommends avoiding such forms in writing. In Esopo topic and accusative particles are always written ua, va and vo, uo, also after /-t/ and /N/, i.e. without renjō, e.g. xujinuo /syuzin-o/ 'master-ACC' or funbetuo /funbet-o/ 'judgement-ACC', although these words would have been pronounced as from /syuzinno/ and /funbetto/.
Renjō thus reflects final /-t/ and also shows that word final /N/ phonetically was [n] (as opposed to NJ where word final /N/ is an unreleased uvular [ɴ] or velar [ŋ]). The difference in application of renjō after /N/ and /-t/ also indicates a difference between those two phonemes in the language, suggesting that final /-t/, which was (almost) only found in SJ vocabulary, was not as stable as other syllable final phonemes, and that it was in the process of acquiring an epenthetic vowel.


Arte = Arte da Lingoa de Iapam
Vocabulario = Vocabulario da Lingoa de Iapam
In 16th/17th-century Portuguese romanization scheme of Japanese:

⟨ǔ⟩ = /uː/ (from earlier /uu/)

⟨ô⟩ = /oː/ (from earlier /ou/ and /eu/)

⟨ǒ⟩ = /ɔː/ (from earlier /au/) (later it merged with /oː/)

⟨x⟩ = /ɕ/ (consonant part of modern し)


